# Machine dependent web application login

Tags: windows, macos, web-applications

Is there a way to limit the login to a web application based on client machine name or id. The requirement is a certain userid login should be done only from pre-determined or preset systems.

Hope this covers the queries mentioned.

I am not sure if IP address of the machine can be used as much effective as the machine name or macid may server the purpose.
Client OS can be windows or mac. Its a public facing site but a certain group of users should login from certain machines only. 
The site is php, mysql and hosted on apache and linux.

Comment: Is an IP address acceptable? That is, will the particular client machine always have the same IP address? Otherwise, this is an *extremely* vague question that's very difficult to answer.

Comment: We are going to need more information.  Are the clients all of the same operating system?  Are they all internal to a business, or is this a public-facing website?  What language will the site be developed in?  What operating system and web server will it be hosted on?

Comment: Have edited the post with replies to the queries.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, a web browser will only send basic HTTP headers along for the ride, in addition to a known IP address.

Assuming you even could get this information from the client system via javascript, it would not be trustable, (eg, a client could fake it).

Perhaps you can expand your question a bit?

Comment: By faking do you mean the headers that is being send from the client?